# htaccess to redirect root and subfolders language pages to /en

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I would like to use htaccess to redirect [www.domain.com/?lang=en](http://www.domain.com/?lang=en) pages to [www.domain.com/en/](http://www.domain.com/en/) subfolders. I've tried the code below but url with subfolders like [www.domain.com/folder/?lang=en](http://www.domain.com/folder/?lang=en) or [www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/?lang=en](http://www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/?lang=en) are not taken into account by my htaccess rules. Only the root page is well updated from ?lang=en to /en/.

- (KO) domain.com/?lang=en > domain.com/en/
- (KO) domain.com/folder/?lang=en > domain.com/en/folder/
- (KO) domain.com/folder/folder2/?lang=en > domain.com/en/folder/folder2/

Here is what i've tried so far :

```
# BEGIN LANGUAGE REDIRECTION
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en
# exclude all requests starting with /wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /en/$1? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END LANGUAGE REDIRECTION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. This will redirect/rewrite and will add language `en` in your case(as per shown samples) before your URIs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [R=301,NE,QSD,L]
```